# I can't get detail errors in Godgiven PHP-API project

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I'm using Godgiven PHP-API project that's developed by fat-free and I can't get detail errors just give 500 code error how to solve this problem 
thank

[this link of the project](https://bitbucket.org/godgiven-project/php-api/src/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The php-api god-given project use fat-free

if you want to show error details in the front end
you should use

```
$f3->set('DEBUG',3);
```

you can read more [fat-free document](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/framework-variables)